# Predicate interface in Java8

Tags: generics, java-8, predicate

`and()` and `or()` methods of Predicate interface in Java 8 takes any super type of `T`, that is `? super T` and not `? extends T`. I was expecting it to take any type that extends `T`. The motivation for me to think this way is, since `T` is the type I'm defining my predicate on, the compound predicate also should be on `T` (that is any subtype of `T`). What is the reason behind that being `? super T`. Can someone help me understand?

Comment: See [“What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488)

Answer (score 2):

So here is my understanding of it. Suppose we have this:

```
interface MyPredicate<T> {
    boolean test(T t);
}
```

And these declarations:

```
 MyPredicate<? extends Number> p1 = (Number n) -> n.intValue() > 9;
 MyPredicate<Integer> p3 = null;
 MyPredicate<Long> p4 = null;
```

Because `Integer` and `Long` are sub-types of `Number`, we can do this:

```
p1 = p3;
p1 = p4;
```

At the same time, let's suppose `p3` and `p4` are not null. The only types they can accept in test would be `Integer` and `Long`.

```
p3.test(12);
p4.test(12L);
```

But what would `p1` accept? `Integer`, but what if it points to `MyPredicate<Long>`?  `Long`, but what if it points to `MyPredicate<Integer>`?

So there is no way to apply p1 to anything but `null` in this case.

Let's introduce `p2`:

```
MyPredicate<? super Number> p2 = (Number n) -> n.intValue() > 10;
```

Since it uses `super` we can't even do this:

```
p2 = p3; // will not compile
p2 = p4; // will not compile
```

But this time we know that we will have some type that will have `Number` as it's super type, so we can safely apply Number here. Meaning :

```
p2.test(12); // 12 is Number
```

will compile just fine; since we are 100% sure that whatever the type, **it is a super type of Number**.

Let's change `MyPredicate`:

```
    interface MyPredicate<T> {

    boolean test(T t);

    default MyPredicate<T> and(MyPredicate<? extends T> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t); // this will not compile
    }
}
```

Because we have used `extends`, we don't know the actual type, so it will fail, unlike `super`:

```
    interface MyPredicate<T> {

    boolean test(T t);

    default MyPredicate<T> and(MyPredicate<? super T> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t); // compiles just file
    }
}
```

Comment: Eugene, now I understand why using extends will not be helpful. One small correction to your explanation. `? super Number` can take any type that is a super type of Number. In the above explanation you mentioned it will be guaranteed to extend Number which is not true.